# type error when running ionic serve

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

```
There was an error serving your Ionic application: 

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
        at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\utils\npmScripts.js:16:31
        at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
        at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\utils\npmScripts.js:16:31
        at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
        at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
        at flush (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to need some code. Usually though, this can indicate you are trying to do something before the device is ready. Structure your code like so:

```
document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //Do your stuff
    };
```

As that way you know for sure everything is loaded so less likely for null reference exceptions,